# description of localization of pullback at a prime ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, limits-colimits

[image]
Can you please help me to know: How *"the description of localization of* $D$ *at a prime ideal of it"* is?
Thank you.

Comment: What kind of description are you looking for?

Comment: localization of $D$ at a prime ideal of it based on localization of $A$ and $B$ at a prime ideal of them

Comment: Well, there's not any natural way to get a prime ideal of $A$ or $B$ from a prime ideal of $D$ in general...

Comment: what if $\beta$ is surjective or injective? or maybe other good conditions...

Answer (score 2):

You can consider $A$, $B$, and $C$ as $D$-modules via the maps from $D$, and then the square is also a pullback square of $D$-modules.  Since localization is exact, it preserves pullbacks, so if $p\subset D$ is a prime ideal, then $D_p$ can be described as the pullback of $A_p$ and $B_p$ over $C_p$.  Here $A_p=A\otimes_D D_p$ means the localization of $A$ at $p$ as a $D$-module, and similarly for the others.  Note that these can be seen as localizations of $A$, $B$, and $C$ with respect to multiplicatively closed sets (namely, the image of $D\setminus p$ in each of them), but not necessarily with respect to prime ideals.